# How to encapsulate unicode string in quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

What would be the best way to encapsulate the param `q` in double quotes when I do `request.params.get`?

I am trying to get the response q in unicode.

```
q = request.params.get('q', u'')
```

When I save it to this string, lets say I passed `Hello` from my html form, it saves it to the variable q as `u'Hello'`

But how can does one make it output more like `u'"Hello"'`

Comment: `q = '"{0}"'.format(request.params.get('q', ''))` ?

Comment: `q = repr(request.params.get('q', ''))`

Comment: Yup works! @khachik !